# Prove returns inconsistent test results with Test::More and .tap extension

Tags: perl, tap

Attempting to make a basic test using `Test::More`, on a file named `test.tap`:

```perl
use Test::More tests => 2;

is( 1, 1 );
is( 2, 2 );
```

Running `prove` against this test causes a failure:

```
$ prove test.tap
test.tap .. No subtests run

Test Summary Report
-------------------
test.tap (Wstat: 0 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=1, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.02 CPU)
```

But Perl gives a seemingly valid TAP output:

```
$ perl test.tap
1..2
ok 1
ok 2
```

The `prove` version is:

```
$ prove --version
TAP::Harness v3.35 and Perl v5.22.1
```

Additionally, I found that adding a shebang `#!` on the test file causes test results to pass intermittently

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Test::More tests => 2;

is( 1, 1 );
is( 2, 2 );
```

On success (passes ~1 time in 4):

```
t/test.tap .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys +  0.01 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.04 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

I have also found that renaming the file to `test.t` causes the test to pass every time.

In attempting to find a bug in an old version, I have replicated this issue on a fresh DigitalOcean Droplet running Ubuntu 16.04.2, and a Debian 8 host with `TAP::Harness` v3.36_01 and Perl v5.24.1.

I'm hoping to avoid "Rename all files to .t extension" being the answer. I am uncertain what `TAP::Harness` considers to be the difference between those two extensions, and cannot find any documentation or where in the source code that distinction is made.

Any clarification on what is happening is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell it how to run tests: `prove --exec /bin/perl test_more.tap`

Comment: I have confirmed the intermittent passing with the shebang line and would be interested to know how that comes to pass...
The same happens for me when using the file-option extensions parameter to prove: it passes about 1/4 of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.tap` extension tells prove that `test.tap` is a text file which contains TAP. It does not execute it as a Perl program, it just reads the file and tries to parse it as TAP. You can see this with `prove -v`.

```
$ prove -v test.tap
test.tap .. 
use Test::More tests => 2;
is(1,1);
is(2,2);

No subtests run 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
test.tap (Wstat: 0 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=1, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.02 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

Instead, the convention for test programs to execute is `test.t`.

```
$ mv test.tap test.t
$ prove -v test.t
test.t .. 
1..2
ok 1
ok 2
ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys +  0.04 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.07 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

See [TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::File) for more.

---

> *Additionally, I found that adding a shebang to the test file causes test results intermittently pass:*

What's happening is the various TAP::Parser::SourceHandler plugins are all voting about what it is, and it's a tie. [TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::Perl) sees "*a shebang ala "#!...perl*" and votes 0.9. [TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::File) sees a .tap extension and votes 0.9. You can see this by setting the `TAP_HARNESS_SOURCE_FACTORY_VOTES` environment variable.

```
$ TAP_HARNESS_SOURCE_FACTORY_VOTES=1  prove test.tap
votes: TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::File: 0.9, TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::Perl: 0.9
test.tap .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys +  0.05 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.08 CPU)
Result: PASS

$ TAP_HARNESS_SOURCE_FACTORY_VOTES=1  prove test.tap
votes: TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::Perl: 0.9, TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::File: 0.9
test.tap .. No subtests run 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
test.tap (Wstat: 0 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=1, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.01 sys =  0.03 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

The handlers are then sorted by votes. Since Perl's sort is not stable, that is if two entries are equal it does not preserve their order, either handler can come out on top. Even using stable sort, it's sorting from `keys %handlers` which will come out in a different order each process. [Here's the code for that](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/blob/b31070bef9c31301d7788d58495095724dbebadb/lib/TAP/Parser/IteratorFactory.pm#L268).

For a test harness to not be deterministic in its decisions is bad. It should probably instead throw an error. I also note it's using a string comparison, which is probably wrong.

[I've submitted a patch to make ties an error](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/pull/67).

Comment: Excellent answer.  *"For a test harness to not be deterministic in its decisions is bad"* I agree, despite this issue not arising if `Test::Harness` *were* determinstic. Will you raise this as a Perl bug?

Comment: @Borodin [Already submitted a PR](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Test-Harness/pull/67). :)

Comment: I really dislike code and data presented in the same style as narrative English. For instance, "TAP::Parser::SourceHandler::Perl sees "a shebang ala "*#!...perl*" is no language that I know. Markdown has backticks to mark preformatted text, and I wonder why you don't use it?